# Yosemite WiFi dead chip

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, macos

I have noticed a weird WiFi bug with OS X Yosemite. This has never happened in any previous OS X that I have used. I have a Early 2013 Macbook Pro with Retina display 13 and I updated to Yosemite a day after it launched. I usually do not shut down my laptop and just keep it in sleep. After the update, sometimes when the laptop wakes up from sleep WiFi is completely switched off. On trying to turn it on I get the following message in console:

```
22/10/14 1:41:11.000 pm kernel[0]: ARPT: 1911.087562: wl0: _wlc_ioctl: dead chip, off[0] bar0[0xffffffff]
```

Upon restart the WiFI icon becomes a grey icon with a cross mark and says either "No hardware installed" or "WiFi not configured".

The only solution I have found till now is an SMC reset. But with the frequency of this happening is quite high and is frustrating to always shutdown and do an SMC reset. Is anyone else facing similar issues? And does anyone know of a fix without a restart ?

Comment: I have been having [this issue](https://discussions.apple.com/message/28882638?tstart=0#28882638) occasionally also.  So far I haven't found any fix without a restart.  I'm waiting to hear back from Apple Support on the bug report I filed.

Answer (score 1):

You may have hardware that is on it's way to being really dead.  The temperature of a marginal chip can cause it to be functional sometimes and non-functional other times.  When you resume from sleep, try letting the computer get warm, then try to enable WiFi.  The chip may need to get warm and then work.  This is obviously not a good long term solution but, if it works, it indicates that the chip (or the connection to the board) is flakey.

Comment: It definitely is a software issue because it doesn't explain the chip working right after an NVRAM and SMC reset. The issue does seem to have been fixed in 10.11 and my card is running fine till now, over a year since I put up that question

Comment: I have this issue in El Capitan.  Just started happening.

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to have been fixed in OS X 10.11 El Capitan, like you mentioned in [your comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/97730/user2959757).

Comment: I have this issue in El Capitan.  Just started happening.